# Is there an adelic proof of Gallagher's ergodic theorem?

Tags: nt.number-theory, diophantine-approximation

Gallagher's ergodic theorem in Diophantine approximation states that the approximation of real numbers by rationals obeys a striking 'all or nothing' behaviour.

For the sake of fixing notation, I'll state it as a proposition about points of finite order on the circle $\mathbb{S} = \mathbb{R} / \mathbb{~Z}$:

> **Proposition** Let $\delta_1, \delta_2, \ldots$ be a sequence of real numbers and let,
>   $$
>     W = \limsup_{n > 0} \{ z \in \mathbb{S} ~|~ \exists~ y \in \mathbb{S}, |y - z| < \delta_n, o(y) = n\}.
>   $$
> Then $W =_{a.e.} \emptyset$ or $W =_{a.e.} \mathbb{S}$.

I only know one proof of this result and I find it somewhat remarkable: there is a separate "local" argument for each prime and then one more "global" argument that uses all primes simultaneously. This makes me wonder:

> **Question** Is there an adelic point of view for the proof of Gallagher's theorem or at least some insight into the proof strategy?

I freely admit that I am no number theorist so perhaps this sort of argument is far more typical than I realise and just par for the course?

I'll finish by giving a very brief outline of the proof strategy, highlighting the groups that (implicitly) play a key role.
The idea is that for any prime $p$ we can write $W = A_p \cup B_p \cup C_p$ where:
$$
\begin{align*}
 A_p &= \limsup_{n > 0, p \mid n} \{ z \in \mathbb{S} ~|~ \exists~ y \in \mathbb{S}, |y - z| < \delta_n, o(y) = n\},\\
 B_p &= \limsup_{n > 0, p \mid\mid n} \{ z \in \mathbb{S} ~|~ \exists~ y \in \mathbb{S}, |y - z| < \delta_n, o(y) = n\},\\
 C_p &= \limsup_{n > 0, p^2 \mid n} \{ z \in \mathbb{S} ~|~ \exists~ y \in \mathbb{S}, |y - z| < \delta_n, o(y) = n\}.
\end{align*}
$$
These sets have the following key properties:

(a) $A_p$ is almost invariant under the ergodic map $y \mapsto py$,

(b) $B_p$ is almost invariant under the ergodic map $y \mapsto py + [1/p]$,

(c) $C_p$ is invariant under the map $y \mapsto y + [1/p]$.

Given the above, the argument is that if $A_p$ is not almost empty for any $p$ then by ergodicity it must be almost $\mathbb{S}$ and thus so also must $W$ and we're done. Similarly for $B_p$. We thus proceed under the assumption that $A_p$ and $B_p$ are almost empty for all primes $p$. However given this $W =_{a.e.} C_p$ for all $p$ and so $W$ is almost invariant under $y \mapsto y + [1/p]$ for all $p$.

This forces $W$ to be almost empty or almost $\mathbb{S}$ by the following:

> **Lemma** Let $s \subseteq \mathbb{S}$ be measurable and $u_0, u_1, \ldots$ be a sequence of finite-order points in $\mathbb{S}$ such that:
>
> - $u_i + s =_{a.e.} s$ for all $i$,
> - the order $o(u_i) \to \infty$ as $i \to \infty$.
>
> Then $s =_{a.e.} \emptyset$ or $s =_{a.e.} \mathbb{S}$.

Note that in this lemma $s$ is of course almost invariant under the subgroup generated by the $u_i$.

Now as well as finishing the proof of Gallagher's theorem, this lemma can also be used to prove that the maps mentioned in (a) and (b) are ergodic. In a sense Gallagher's theorem thus invokes this lemma:

- Once for each prime $p$, with sequence $u_i = 1/p^i$, generating the $p$-Prüfer subgroup (dual to the p-adic integers).
- Once more with the sequence $u_i = 1/p_i$ (the $i$th prime), generating the subgroup the points of finite square-free order which is abstractly the group $\oplus_p \mathbb{Z}/(p)$ (dual to the direct product).